# System.IO.FileLoadException mismatch

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to create a new ASP.net CORE application but the problem is with each application I build I got the following error message:

```
PM> add-migration Init
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.StartupInvoker.ConfigureHostServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.StartupInvoker.ConfigureServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations..ctor(IOperationReporter reporter, Assembly assembly, Assembly startupAssembly, String environment, String contentRootPath)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations..ctor(IOperationReporter reporter, Assembly assembly, Assembly startupAssembly, String environment, String projectDir, String contentRootPath, String rootNamespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<.ctor>b__4()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I googled to it and found the following that can be the error. a Ref-Def-Mismatch
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2004/03/25/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-with-name-xxx-dll-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference/

Only my problem is that I can't find a solution to this problem. Does anyone got an idea?

my project.json is:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "secret",

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: show your project.json - maybe you are mixing package versions

Comment: I updated the post with my project.json in it right now. You might got an idea?

Comment: Inside frameworks it should be `netcoreapp1.1` according to [the announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/) (Not sure if that's the cause)

Comment: O bro that was the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Daniel J.G. said I needed to update my project.json too the following:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "secret",

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

After that I needed too specify my deps.json.

```
PM> add-migration init
The specified deps.json [C:\Users\ik_ro\Source\Repos\ProjectDotNetCoreTest\src\ProjectDotNetCoreTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\ProjectDotNetCoreTest.deps.json] does not exist
Process finished with non-zero exit code
PM> add-migration init
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
    1.0.1
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.0'.
Process finished with non-zero exit code
```

The location that it searched was:

```
 C:\Users\ik_ro\Source\Repos\ProjectDotNetCoreTest\src\ProjectDotNetCoreTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64
```

But it needed to be:

```
C:\Users\ik_ro\Source\Repos\ProjectDotNetCoreTest\src\ProjectDotNetCoreTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64
```

I copied and paste everything from the win10-x64 folder to the netcoreapp1.1 folder. That solved the problem.